# Mocking an insert method of a repository

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, moq

I would like to unit test the following method:

```
void Insert(TEntity entity);
```

The class of this method is already mocked (I'm using Moq).

Now I'd like to do a state based test and tell Moq if this method is called, an object has to be inserted to a list.
How can I do that?

```
useraccountRepository.Setup(r => r.Insert(useraccountBeforeLogin)).???
```

What comes here? There's a raises method which would raise an event. Can I use this?

Answer (score 11):

I know this is an old thread, but this is what I did to test that items are inserted from a mocked repository, hopefully this might help someone.

```
var myRepositoryMock = new Mock<IMyRepository>();

var itemsInserted = new List<MyItem>();

myRepositoryMock 
    .Setup(i => i.InsertItem(It.IsAny<MyItem>()))
    .Callback((MyItem item) => itemsInserted.Add(item));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [callbacks](http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart#Callbacks) - there's a few examples listed there

Comment: Thank you.
Basically it works now:
List<Useraccount> useraccountsAfterRegister = new List<Useraccount>();

            useraccountRepository.Setup(r => r.Insert(useraccountBeforeLogin)).Callback(
                () => useraccountsAfterRegister.Add(useraccountAfterLogin));

But is this a real state based test? Could also be an interaction test because I tell the mockup what happens when the insert method is called.